# Why is my Brother DCP-7055 not printing in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: drivers, 13.10, printing

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 13.10. Actually,it was a new installation (I reformatted the drives before installing 13.10).

Everything seems nice and new. I installed my *Brother DCP-7055 printer/copier/scanner machine* properly. The OS recognized the printer, it is listed with the *lsusb* command and I was even able to access it from my browser, through the URL: `localhost:631/printers/`.

Then, when I clicked Print Test Page, it wasn't printing.  I thought it was just taking longer, but ten minutes later, nothing happened. My printer even has already gone into deep sleep, and still nothing. So, I assumed it really won't print. The machine's scanner feature was tested and worked well, by the way, with Simple Scan.

It worked well with 12.04 LTS. It will just be sad to downgrade to it.

So what's wrong with it ?

How can I fix it ?

Comment: I tried printing text in Leafpad while logged as root, 'thinking that it was due to admin priviledges. When the Print dialog box came up, the status says, "Waiting for printer to become available". That's strange, because my printer is on, and is listed with the lsusb command.  And this never happened before in 12.04.

Comment: Oh well, our small business can't wait any longer. It's sad, but the only workaround I have right now is to revert back to Ubuntu 12.04. Anyway, it is supported until 2017. I just hope future versions of Ubuntu will be nice stomping grounds once more for my Brother printer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=590793

Copy/pasting for reference:

Step 1:
Open Terminal by selecting Applications ---- Terminal from the task bar.

Step 2:
Type or Copy & Paste the following into Terminal and press enter:

```
sudo apt-get install tcsh
```

Step 3: (don't know if it matters but I did it anyway)
From the task bar go to: System ---- Administration ---- Printing, select your printer that's not working then select edit and click delete.

Step 4:
Download the LPR Driver and CUPS Wrapper. Locate your model & download your "Debian" LPR printer driver from HERE.
Locate your model & download your "Debian" CUPS wrapper from [HERE.](http://solutions.brother.com/linux/sol/printer/linux/lpr_drivers.html)

Step 5:
Now change to the directory where the drivers are. Presuming you downloaded the driver to your desktop Type or Copy & Paste the following into Terminal:

```
   cd Desktop
```

Step 6:
Create the lpd directory. This is the first I have encountered this but in Hardy the directory had to be created. Skip this and move on to Step 7 if you're using Gutsy or below. In terminal Type or Copy & Paste the following command:

```
    sudo mkdir /var/spool/lpd
```

Step 7:
Install the LPR Driver. In terminal Type or Copy & Paste the following command changing mfc210clpr-1.0.2-1.i386.deb to match the driver you've downloaded. The following line is for the MFC-210C which is also used for the following printers:
DCP-115C, DCP-117C, DCP-120C, DCP-315CN, DCP-340CW,MFC-215C, MFC-425CN, MFC-640CW, MFC-820CW

```
  sudo dpkg -i --force-all mfc210clpr-1.0.2-1.i386.deb
```

Step 8:
Create the model directory. As with the lpd directory this is the first I have encountered this but in Hardy the directory had to be created. Skip this and move on to Step 9 if you're using Gutsy or below. In terminal Type or Copy & Paste the following command:

```
  sudo mkdir /usr/share/cups/model
```

Step 9:
Now to install the CUPS wrapper driver. In terminal Type or Copy & Paste the following command changing cupswrapperMFC210C-1.0.2-3.i386.deb to match the driver you've downloaded.The following line is for the MFC-210C which is also used for the following printers:
DCP-115C, DCP-117C, DCP-120C, DCP-315CN, DCP-340CW,MFC-215C, MFC-425CN, MFC-640CW, MFC-820CW

```
  sudo dpkg -i --force-all cupswrapperMFC210C-1.0.2-3.i386.deb
```

After the installation observe that there are no errors. Here are 2 examples of a successful and unsuccessful installation:

Successful:

```
  matthew@matthew-laptop:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg -i --force-all             cupswrapperMFC210C-1.0.2-3.i386.deb
  [sudo] password for matthew:
  (Reading database ... 119742 files and directories currently installed.)
  Preparing to replace cupswrappermfc210c 1.0.2-3 (using cupswrapperMFC210C-1.0.2-3.i386.deb) ...
   * Restarting Common Unix Printing System: cupsd                               [ OK ] 
  Unpacking replacement cupswrappermfc210c ...
  Setting up cupswrappermfc210c (1.0.2-3) ...
  rm -f /usr/lib/cups/filter/brlpdwrapperMFC210C
   * Restarting Common Unix Printing System: cupsd                         [ OK ] 

  matthew@matthew-laptop:~/Desktop$
```

Unsuccessful:

```
    turner@turner-desktop:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg -i --force-all cupswrapperMFC210C-1.0.2-3.i386.deb
    [sudo] password for turner:
    Selecting previously deselected package cupswrappermfc210c.
    (Reading database ... 91832 files and directories currently installed.)
    Unpacking cupswrappermfc210c (from cupswrapperMFC210C-1.0.2-3.i386.deb) ...
    Setting up cupswrappermfc210c (1.0.2-3) ...
    ERROR : Brother LPD filter is not installed.
    rm -f /usr/lib/cups/filter/brlpdwrapperMFC210C
    chmod: cannot access `/usr/local/Brother/inf/brMFC210Crc': No such       file or directory
    chmod: cannot access `/usr/local/Brother/inf': No such file or directory
     * Restarting Common Unix Printing System: cupsd                         [ OK ]
```

If your installation was successful please continue at Step 10. If it was unsuccessful please repeat the installation at the LPR Driver installation at Step 7. Copy the output(text from the install commands in the terminal) of both the LPR and CUPS driver installations and save them to a text document for future reference. As there have been reports of errors but the the printer still worked perfectly you may have no problem. Continue on with Step 10.

Step 10: (This is for Gutsy 64bit users only, 32bit users continue onto Step 11 )
If you're using the MFC-210C driver Type or Copy & Paste the following command in Terminal:

```
  sudo cp /usr/lib/cups/filter/brlpdwrapperMFC210C /usr/lib64/cups/filter
```

If you're using another driver please adjust MFC210C to suit your model. Example for the MFC-3820CN driver:

```
  sudo cp /usr/lib/cups/filter/brlpdwrapperMFC3820CN /usr/lib64/cups/filter
```

If you're not sure you can check by typing the following in Terminal:

```
   cd /usr/lib/cups/filter
   dir
```

Step 11:
From the task bar go to: System ---- Administration ---- Printing, select your printer and click Print Test Page. That's It!

Please note that adjusting printer settings for all applications takes place in this Printing Configuration menu by selecting your printer then selecting the tab Printer Options.

Not working?
Some printers might not configure themselves without a few more adjustments as follows:

After completing the driver installation open Firefox and enter the following into the address bar:

```
   http://localhost:631
```

Click on “Manage Printers” and confirm that the driver name is listed there.

If the driver name is NOT listed there, click on "Add Printer" and install the driver following the on-screen instructions.

The default port is USB. If you want to use a different port, click on “Modify Printer” and select the required printer port.

Scanner:

Unfortunately the Sane Scanner Driver wasn't quite as straight forward to setup, however it will be a lot easier with these steps:

FIRST MAKE SURE YOUR SYSTEM HAS ALL UPDATES INSTALLED IF YOU HAVE A FRESH INSTALLATION OF UBUNTU.

Step 1:
Locate your model & download the appropriate "Debian" brscan or brscan2 driver from HERE. Please take note that there is a separate driver depending on whether you have a 32bit or 64bit Gutsy installed. Typically it will be 32bit.

Step 2:
Now change to the directory where the brscan or brscan2 driver has downloaded to. Presuming you downloaded the driver to your desktop Type or Copy & Paste the following into Terminal:

```
   cd Desktop
```

Step 3:
For the brscan2 32bit driver which most will be using Install with the following command in Terminal:

```
   sudo dpkg -i brscan2-0.2.4-0.i386.deb
```

Please note that if you don't use the 32bit brscan2 driver change the brscan2-0.2.4-0.i386.deb in the terminal command above according to your sane driver you've downloaded. Example: brscan2-0.2.4-0.amd64.deb

Step 4:
Confirm you need to continue on with the following steps, I believe it is only Gutsy that has problems. Simply open Xsane, choose you scanner and click OK. If you get an I/O-Error you will need to continue onto Step 5, if it's all working you're done!

Step 5:
Give yourself permission to use it! At time of release it's a Gutsy Quirk/Bug... First we need to find out the Vendor ID & Product ID for our scanner or printer/scanner combo. For anyone using the DCP-115C printer/scanner ignore this step as your ID's are the same as mine; Vendor ID: 04f9 Product ID: 018c.

Any other model type the following in Terminal:

```
   lsusb
```

Your output will be something like this:

```
   matthew@matthew-laptop:~/Desktop$ lsusb
   Bus 005 Device 004: ID 05ca:1810 Ricoh Co., Ltd 
   Bus 005 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
   Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03f0:171d Hewlett-Packard 
   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
   Bus 002 Device 003: ID 062a:0000 Creative Labs Optical Mouse
   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
   Bus 004 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f9:018c Brother Industries, Ltd 
   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
   matthew@matthew-laptop:~/Desktop$
```

Locate Brother Industries, Ltd and take note of your Vendor IDroduct ID as shown in bold in the above output and adjust Step 6 to match.

Step 6:
In Terminal type the following:

Ubuntu:
       sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/45-libsane.rules
Kubuntu:
       sudo kate /etc/udev/rules.d/45-libsane.rules

At the bottom of the page but before LABEL="libsane_rules_end" add the following changing YOUR-VENOR-ID & YOUR- PRODUCT-ID to yours, both are 4 characters long:

```
   # Brother DCP-115C
   SYSFS{idVendor}=="YOUR-VENOR-ID", SYSFS{idProduct}=="YOUR-PRODUCT-ID", MODE="664", GROUP="scanner"
```

The last section of 45-libsane.rules should look like this after adding your scanner/printer to the last line:

```
   SYSFS{idVendor}=="413c", SYSFS{idProduct}=="5105", MODE="664", GROUP="scanner"
   # Dell A960
   SYSFS{idVendor}=="413c", SYSFS{idProduct}=="5107", MODE="664", GROUP="scanner"
   # Dell 922
```

SYSFS{idVendor}=="413c", SYSFS{idProduct}=="5109", MODE="664", GROUP="scanner"
       # Dell 1600n
SYSFS{idVendor}=="413c", SYSFS{idProduct}=="5250", MODE="664", GROUP="scanner"
       # Brother DCP-115C
SYSFS{idVendor}=="04f9", SYSFS{idProduct}=="018c", MODE="664", GROUP="scanner"

```
   LABEL="libsane_rules_end"
```

Step 7:
Save your changes and restart your PC. All going well it will be working!